# what went wrong with my Variable banner program?

Tags: python-3.x

I've started work on a Variable banner program, and I've hit a "phantom" syntax error.

```
name = input('Type here: ')
namelist = list(namelist)
print(namelist)
length_of_name=len(namelist)
asterisk=('*')

for length_of_name:
print (asterisk)
```

it throws up a syntax error, as I mentioned, but can anyone spot what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The SyntaxError is coming from your for statement. A for statement has to look like `for variable in sequence_object:`. Here `sequence_object` is any type that can be iterated, such as a list or tuple, but in your particular case `for i in range(0,length_of_name):` will make the code syntactically correct. But don't use this because there is a faster way which makes exactly the same output.

Instead of printing a single character in a loop, set `asterisk` to `'*\n'` and use `print(asterisk*length_of_name, end='')`. This prints the same output as the for loop but this multiplies the asterisk character by an integer to make a string that is repeated that many times. That way, you only print once. Setting `end` to an empty string ensures that a blank line is not printed.